# What is the differencce between MongoDB Atlas and MongoDB Atlas for AWS

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, aws-marketplace

During my investigation on compatible DBs for IoT data storing I looked into MongoDB and pricing is a little bit confusing.

Just wondering what is the difference between [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/pricing) and [MongoDB Atlas for AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B077D557RX) as they both work on AWS?

And what is the right way to run MongoDB Atlas on AWS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can see, they both should mostly be similar :

**MongoDB Atlas :**

You can directly go to [MongoDB-Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) portal & create a MongoDB cluster(a cluster will usually be 3-shard/node replica set on which a DB is hosted) on either of the cloud providers (**AWS**/**Google**/**Azure**). This way all database updates/maintenance will usually be done by vendor. Quiet easy & simple - Which most people are opting for these days (SAAS/ db hosted on cloud). You can also opt for a free cluster which should be suitable for basic needs kind of learning MongoDB. While creating cluster you can check for pricing which is based on cluster level (M0 to M700), You can upgrade your cluster when ever you wish to, but when I was creating one I've noted that you would pay upfront for a certain amount of years likely 3 & whether you use the money or not you would not get anything back but it you've paid less then you might be charged over the time of usage. You'll pay bills thru MongoDB Atlas.

**MongoDB Atlas for AWS** :

From here [aws-marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B077D557RX) when you see the text marketplace (where multiple companies/people collaborate to sell products) it's basically these two companies have collaborated to provide MongoDB as SAAS. With this you can actually come from **AWS** rather than than **Atlas** from itself. When it comes to pricing `AWS` seems to provide some credits, It would be better if you can consult **AWS** & **Atlas** to check on their pricing & other terms if you really wanted to use it for enterprise purpose. You might end-up owing an AWS account to pay bills for this usage (Which hectic if you don't use AWS for other use-cases). Additionally if you check below on MongoDB Atlas for AWS page it seems like just a starting point is given at **AWS** side but entire setup would be done at **Atlas**.

> You're charged for your purchase on your AWS bill. After you purchase
>   a contract, you're directed to the vendor's site to complete setup and
>   begin using this software.

Comment: From my exp an avg web applications dev/qa/prod mongodb atlas servers can cost an avg of 8k to 25k $ per month, Please dont take this as is, it all depends on usage and rates as of that day..

Comment: As I can see on the AWS Marketplace page there is only one price for using Atlas bought on AWS, it is $2K per month. But there are few different prices for M0-M700 clusters on the MongoDB side. Why is it so huge difference between prices on AWS and MongoDB for the same product? And what is definitely sold on AWS for $2K?

Comment: @kolyaiks : not exactly sure about it, as I said for an avg customer facing retail product/website (if you're using MongoDB for Dev/Qa/Prod with an avg. of M50 clusters and have around 8 clusters in total) depending upon your DB usage you could get a bill anywhere from 10k to 30k$ per month on Atlas(billing depends on various factors disk size/iops/ram size/ backups). Again AWS billing might not be straight forward they might be charging a base of 2k$ and may be adding extras going forward. You can always request either of the teams to analyze/estimate your usage for free, contact them..

Comment: I've written to them, but have no answer. Thanks for your experience!