# Mongodb database after a few day, suddenly it deleted automatically?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mern

after I deployed my application and used it for a few days, suddenly it deleted automatically, I have no idea what happened to my mongoDB. Can anyone give me the suggestions or ideas of what happened to my application regarding the mongoDB? Thank you.

Cloud server: Digitalocean
Technology: MERN Stack Application

Comment: Where is your MongoDB hosted on ? There should be DB logs which says what commands got executed on DB !!

Comment: I host the mongodb on digital ocean cloud server. So how do I find the log file directory.

Comment: Yes could be an attack as you've already suspected, it's quiet common. But before confirming check for logs, not sure about digital ocean deployments, but in general check this :: https://mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-where-is-the-log-file/ , Also you can check MongoDB Atlas which is cloud based mongodb service maintained by MongoDB itself which is secured..

Comment: Here is a warning log file from mongodb, ```2020-02-11T14:43:20.261+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2020-02-11T14:43:20.261+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.``` If I'm going to use MongoDB cloud Atlas, is it free? Do you have any idea or guidelines to setup it? Thank you.

Comment: yes as you’ve already said that your db is publicly accessible, which shouldn’t be in the first place. I would assume you might not have taken any backup it’s unfortunate to hear.. check for any suspicious IP addresses or any long running queries (if db profiler is set but I would assume its not, anyway by default queries >100ms should be logged, not sure about collection drop logs) that got executed these might not get data but maybe to know what happened also..

Comment: mongodb atlas has free version which you can signup and try which should be sufficient enough for learning and for initial days as well you can upgrade as per your needs at anytime check with their policies, you can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/q/60263057/7237613 for basic info...

Comment: Thank you whoami, do you have any firewall rule recommendation for secure the mongoDB(ufw) hosted on digital ocean and do you know how to remove the ```WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database. ** Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.``` because when I start mongo shell it that warning, but I already create an admin account in the mongo shell, any idea brother.

Comment: not sure about mongo hosted in digital ocean but in general you need to limit your accessible ip addresses check how to do that in self hosted mongodbs that way you can control who can access and that might solve those warnings

Answer (score 0):

is the directory there that it was in?....does it contain files?
sounds like you need to talk to the hosting company

Comment: It's not related to the hosting, actually, I deploy code to digital ocean and install node js, react, mongo and other stuff as normal. All the users will be able to access it through public IP address, we were using a few days and suddenly in the morning all the database that created is gone. Is it a problem with security of set up ubuntu cloud server because when I check in stack overflow most of them said, it attack by hacker or virus, but I'm not sure. Please give some suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: are you saying just a database is gone and mongod is operating (there can be multiple databases)…. or is the whole mongod file set gone?

Comment: Yes, only the database inside the application is gone, but the application is still running and operate with no database. Can you recommend some suggestions to prevent what happened again? Thank you.

Comment: one needs to review the log file back in time to see the event that dropped the db....then you'll get some insight on how that happened and therefore how to prevent....basically I think it is a human/permissions thing....but...that's why you want to find/look at the log event

Comment: Thank you for catching up with my issue, Cahaba Data. Now I just created a new Database and change some firewall rules inside my Digital Ocean server, I just found a vulnerable in my firewall rule, because I allowed the port node server and MongoDB and I think it was the problem. Then I just block that block from outside access and I feel like everything is working fine till now.

Comment: to drop a database is a Mongo command - so you should double check the Mongo permissions for the users...permissions are part of the defined security role assigned to users and so it comes down to checking the roles for your users...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes these errors can occur due to **lack of security**, such as not setting a user without admin permissions to use mongo.

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69751702/15498342), I explained how you could set one admin user and another with only write and read permissions.