# Mongodb data in EC2 instance get deleted automatically

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Using Nodejs,Severless framework created Lamda function in AWS and mongoDB deployed in EC2 instance.
All connection are fine and the application ran successfully.
But somehow data in Mongodb(inside EC2 instance) get erased automatically after certain interval of time(approx after 1 day)
Please suggest what changes are required in Lamda function or in EC2 instance to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with **mongo's authentication**. If you define an **administrator** user and another user with **only read and write** permissions on the database, this problem is solved:

To set the admin user, simply set the following mongo environment variables:

```
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=username_for_admin
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password_for_admin
MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=database_name
```

To define the other user define the following variables:

```
MONGO_URL=mongo:27017
MONGO_DB=database_name
MONGO_USERNAME=username_for_normal_user
MONGO_PASSWORD=password_for_normal_user
```

After that, just create the following script to **add** the user when mongo is started:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

mongo <<EOF
use admin
db.createUser({
  user:  '$MONGO_USERNAME',
  pwd: '$MONGO_PASSWORD',
  roles: [{
    role: 'readWrite',
    db: 'database_name'
  }]
})
EOF
```

When you connect to the database, put the user in the **mongo url**, like this (if it is javascript or typescript it is exactly this):

`mongo://${process.env.MONGO_USERNAME}:${process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD}@${process.env.MONGO_URL}/${process.env.MONGO_DB}?authSource=admin`

Finally, you have to go to the mongo.conf file and add the following fields:

```
# mongod.conf

#(...)

security:
  authorization: "enabled"

#(...)
```